# Selecting Random items from Dictionary of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

I am trying to randomly select a specific number of sequences from a dictionary of lists and then append these sequences to a new list, but I keep receiving an empty list. My code:

```
final_List = []
num = [["ENST", "10", "5"], ["ENGT", "8", "2"], ["ENHT", "5", "1"]]
a = {"ENST" : ['acac', 'tgtgtgt', 'hahah'], "ENHT": ['aaaa', 'tttt', 'gig', 
'cccc'], 'ENGT' : ['ddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'hhhh', 'pppp']}

for line in num:
    for k, v in a.items():
        if line[0] == k:
            for i in int(line[1] -1):
                final_List.append([k, random.choice(0, len(v))])
```

I am comparing line[0] with k, and if they are the same, I want to pull random sequences from v. The number of sequences I want is the number at line[1]. The final_List would look like:

```
final_List = [["ENST", "acac"], ["ENST", tgtgtgt"]...10 lists with header "ENST"
              ["ENGT", "ddd"], .....8 lists with header "ENGT"
              ["ENHT","aaaa"], ..... 5 lists with header "ENHT"
```

Comment: then do you mean "for i in int(line[1]):" instead of "for i in int(line[1] -1):"?

Comment: probably `for i in range(int(line[1])):`

Comment: You are "receiving an empty list" because the code has errors, which would have been good to point out.  Your question suggests it runs to completion but produces the wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nested list comprehension:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import random
>>> num = [["ENST", "10", "5"], ["ENGT", "8", "2"], ["ENHT", "5", "1"]]
>>> a = {"ENST" : ['acac', 'tgtgtgt', 'hahah'], "ENHT": ['aaaa', 'tttt', 'gig', 
... 'cccc'], 'ENGT' : ['ddd', 'eeee', 'ffff', 'hhhh', 'pppp']}
>>> res = [[[k, random.choice(a[k])] for _ in range(int(count))] for k, count, _ in num]
>>> pprint.pprint(res)
[[['ENST', 'acac'],
  ['ENST', 'tgtgtgt'],
  ['ENST', 'hahah'],
  ['ENST', 'hahah'],
  ['ENST', 'tgtgtgt'],
  ['ENST', 'tgtgtgt'],
  ['ENST', 'hahah'],
  ['ENST', 'acac'],
  ['ENST', 'acac'],
  ['ENST', 'tgtgtgt']],
 [['ENGT', 'pppp'],
  ['ENGT', 'ffff'],
  ['ENGT', 'eeee'],
  ['ENGT', 'hhhh'],
  ['ENGT', 'pppp'],
  ['ENGT', 'eeee'],
  ['ENGT', 'pppp'],
  ['ENGT', 'pppp']],
 [['ENHT', 'cccc'],
  ['ENHT', 'aaaa'],
  ['ENHT', 'gig'],
  ['ENHT', 'tttt'],
  ['ENHT', 'cccc']]]
```

In above `for k, count, _ in num` will iterate over elements in `num` and unpack them to respective variables. Note that we only need the name and count so the throwaway variable is named as `_`:

```
>>> [(k, count) for k, count, _ in num]
[('ENST', '10'), ('ENGT', '8'), ('ENHT', '5')]
```

For every element in `num` a list is constructed by selecting `count` elements from respective list in `a` with [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> k = 'ENST'
>>> count = '10'
>>> [[k, random.choice(a[k])] for _ in range(int(count))]
[['ENST', 'tgtgtgt'], ['ENST', 'hahah'], ['ENST', 'acac'], ['ENST', 'hahah'], ['ENST', 'tgtgtgt'], ['ENST', 'hahah'], ['ENST', 'hahah'], ['ENST', 'hahah'], ['ENST', 'acac'], ['ENST', 'acac']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line where you make the random choice. You are using `random.choice` incorrectly. Also, we want to make sure you are iterating over line[1] correctly. The lines:

```
for i in int(line[1] -1):
    final_List.append([k, random.choice(0, len(v))])
```

should be

```
for i in range(int(line[1])):
    final_List.append([k, random.choice(v)])
```

Comment: int(?) isn't iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the list comprehension idea, but I would use a function to make it a bit clearer

```
def create_sequence(hdr, count):
     return [[hdr, random.choice(a[hdr])] for _ in range(count)]

final_list = [create_sequence(hdr, int(count)) for hdr,count,_ in num]
```